# Logging truck deliveries program?

Tags: web-apps, open-source

I'm looking for a web application preferably PHP and HTML that will allow me to log truck traffic for my company. Example, name, company, delivery number, time, reason for visit if not delivering.. etc

I know I can write one if there isn't an existent out there, but why reinvent the wheel if there is one already?

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a couple ways. You can do it via a google form to log it to a spreadsheet. Pretty simple there. Second, you can check out https://www.bitballoon.com/. If you create a web form it automatically creates a DB for you. There is a free version which would give you a sub domain of something.bitballoon.com. You can shorten that by using a URL shortening service. There is also a low cost $5 option w/ a domain.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, however, I think I may neeed a little more advanced than a form. I need the ability to create various reports based on the data, retrieve particular log records and edit them to the appropriate user with permissions.